# Is there a way to suppress the path of the py file when running python?

Tags: python, windows, path

I have all my python files in the directory ..\..\pydir and run them elsewhere.  At the moment I have to run my python file using:

```
python ..\..\pydir\test.py
```

I would rather not have to specify the path to the python files.  I have put ..\..\pydir in the PATH environment variable and tried:

```
python test.py
```

But this does not work, it can't find the file.  Is there some python path I can use to refer to the python file location?

Answer (score 1):

[Command line](https://docs.python.org/3.10/using/cmdline.html#command-line):

> When invoking Python, you may specify any of these options:
>
> ```
> python [-bBdEhiIOqsSuvVWx?] [-c command | -m module-name | script | - ] [args]
> ```
>
> …
>
> `<script>`
>  Execute the Python code contained in script, which
> **must be a filesystem path (absolute or relative)** referring to either a Python file, a directory containing a `__main__.py` file, or
> a zipfile containing a `__main__.py` file.

Comment: So I have to use ..\..\pydir\test.py, there is no path variable to suppress the folder name.